# Flutter, How to set the page back to portrait mode from landscape

Tags: flutter, dart

I have set my app screen orientation to portrait by adding

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

to my android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml and so when I start my app it's locked to portrait mode. And I am happy about it.

I have a page that shows videos and I am using **Chewie** plugin for it which plays the video in landscape mode all good.

Here is my code:

```
    class _VideoState extends State<Video> {
  ChewieController _chewieController;
 

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _chewieController = ChewieController(
      fullScreenByDefault: true,
      videoPlayerController: widget.videoPlayerController,
      aspectRatio:  16 / 9,
      autoInitialize: true,
      autoPlay: true,
      allowedScreenSleep: false,
      allowFullScreen: true,
      deviceOrientationsAfterFullScreen: [
        DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
        DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
      ],
      errorBuilder: (context, e) {
        return Center(
          child: Text('Some error occurred'),
        );
      },
    );
}

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Chewie(
            controller: _chewieController,
       ),
    );
  }


  @override
  void dispose() {
    widget.videoPlayerController.dispose();
    widget.videoPlayerController.pause();
    _chewieController.dispose();
    super.dispose();

  }
}
```

This works fine till I run the video completely in landscape more with no issues, but when I pop back to my previous page my app which should be in portrait mode is now in landscape mode which I don't want to happen. I want my app to be still locked to portrait mode.

I did try adding SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations to my video page and dispose off but this did not work either.

Any help is appreciated.

Here is the error I get :

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY FOUNDATION LIBRARY ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown while dispatching notifications for VideoPlayerController:
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4182 pos 12:
'_debugLifecycleState != _ElementLifecycle.defunct': is not true.

Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially
more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=BUG.md

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#2      Element.markNeedsBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4182:12)
#3      State.setState (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1260:14)
#4      _VideoState.initState.<anonymous closure> (package:/widget/page/video.dart:65:9)
#5      ChangeNotifier.notifyListeners (package:flutter/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart:209:21)
#6      ValueNotifier.value= (package:flutter/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart:276:5)
#7      VideoPlayerController.pause (package:video_player/video_player.dart:360:5)
#8      _VideoState.dispose (package:/widget/page/video.dart:107:34)
#9      StatefulElement.unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4773:12)
(elided 5 frames from class _AssertionError and dart:async)

The VideoPlayerController sending notification was:
  VideoPlayerController#2afe2(VideoPlayerValue(duration: 0:10:55.430000, size: Size(1920.0, 1080.0),
  position: 0:10:55.430000, caption: Instance of 'Caption', buffered: [DurationRange(start:
  0:00:00.000000, end: 0:10:55.430000)], isPlaying: false, isLooping: false, isBuffering:
  falsevolume: 1.0, errorDescription: null))
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by foundation library ════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown while dispatching notifications for VideoPlayerController:
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4182 pos 12: '_debugLifecycleState != _ElementLifecycle.defunct': is not true.


Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=BUG.md

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#2      Element.markNeedsBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4182:12)
#3      State.setState (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1260:14)
#4      _VideoState.initState.<anonymous closure> (package:/widget/page/video.dart:65:9)
#5      ChangeNotifier.notifyListeners (package:flutter/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart:209:21)
#6      ValueNotifier.value= (package:flutter/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart:276:5)
...
The VideoPlayerController sending notification was: VideoPlayerController#2afe2(VideoPlayerValue(duration: 0:10:55.430000, size: Size(1920.0, 1080.0), position: 0:10:55.430000, caption: Instance of 'Caption', buffered: [DurationRange(start: 0:00:00.000000, end: 0:10:55.430000)], isPlaying: false, isLooping: false, isBuffering: falsevolume: 1.0, errorDescription: null))
```

**Here is my updated code:**

```
class Video extends StatefulWidget {
  final VideoPlayerController videoPlayerController;

  const Video({
    Key key,
    @required this.videoPlayerController,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _VideoState createState() => _VideoState();
}

class _VideoState extends State<Video> {
  ChewieController _chewieController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _chewieController = ChewieController(
      fullScreenByDefault: true,
      videoPlayerController: widget.videoPlayerController,
      aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
      autoInitialize: true,
      autoPlay: true,
      allowedScreenSleep: false,
      allowFullScreen: true,
      deviceOrientationsAfterFullScreen: [
        DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
        DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
      ],
      errorBuilder: (context, e) {
        return Center(
          child: Text('Some error occurred'),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //final length = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: VideoScaffold(
            Chewie(
              controller: _chewieController,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    widget.videoPlayerController.dispose();
    widget.videoPlayerController.pause();
    _chewieController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}

class VideoScaffold extends StatefulWidget {
  const VideoScaffold({Key key, this.child}) : super(key: key);

  final Widget child;

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _VideoScaffoldState();
}

class _VideoScaffoldState extends State<VideoScaffold> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
    ]);
    AutoOrientation.landscapeAutoMode();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return widget.child;
  }

  @override
  dispose() {
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
      DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
    ]);
    AutoOrientation.landscapeAutoMode();
    AutoOrientation.portraitUpMode();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Now after doing Navigator.of(context).pop from the video page my app stays in portrait mode but now the issue is I get the above error. Can anyone help me get rid of the error?

Comment: Have you tried adding `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` directly to the activity you want to be shown as portrait only in your Manifest?

Comment: I have added android:screenOrientation="portrait" to my android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Right, do you have more than one activity defined in your manifest? I'm not familiar wiht the Chewy plugin, but presumably it launches its own activity? You can specify `screenOrientation` at the activity level. So define `screenOrientation` in `<activity android:name="portraitActivity">`

Comment: No luck, the issue is still the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add the following to you main.dart

```
DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
```

example

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
    runApp(MyApp());
}


class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
     @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {

      SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
        DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
//ensures portrait at all times. you can override this if necessary
      ]);

      return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
          body: Center(child: Text("A Flutter Example!")),
     ),
   );
  }
}
```

you need to dipose the widgets when done and revert to potrait

```
 @override
  dispose() {
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    ]);
    super.dispose();
  }
```

Comment: Yes, I did. This was my first option and this too did not work. I did try again after your suggestion but the issue is still the same. My app which should be in portrait mode is shown in landscape mode after is pop from my videos page. Any other suggestions?

Comment: As you see my updated code dispose()  is already implemented. My app works fine, all good, but I still get the error message when I come out of my videos page. Is there any way that error gets fixed?